# XML Documentation file is not included in publish folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I've selected "`Xml documentation file`" in my ASP.NET Core MVC application and it displays "`bin\Debug\net452\MyProject.xml`" as output folder. The problem is that this file doesn't exist in publish folder. Do I need to someting additional to include it? Using .NET Core 1.0-RC4 and VS.NET 2017 RC4 (new csproject format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is not implemented in with dotnet publish but will be in the near future: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795

Comment: Code was merged into master. Not release yet though: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1062

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `project.json` then you can control the files and folders that are both included and excluded by the publish process:

```
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.*.json",
      "web.config"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "wwwroot/less"
    ]
  }
```

---

For `.csproj` based projects [here is a good resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj) for replicating old `project.json` settings in XML, for example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\Shared\*.cs" Exclude="..\Shared\Not\*.cs" />
  <EmbeddedResource Include="..\Shared\*.resx" />
  <Content Include="Views\**\*" PackagePath="%(Identity)" />
  <None Include="some/path/in/project.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="in/package.txt" />

  <None Include="notes.txt" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToOutputDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->

  <Content Include="files\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  <None Include="publishnotes.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" />
  <!-- CopyToPublishDirectory = { Always, PreserveNewest, Never } -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I use .NET Core 1.0-RC4 and VS.NET 2017 RC4 (new csproject format, no project.json).

Comment: @dstr Updated my answer to include some `.csproj` information that may help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The `project.json` file should have the `"xmlDoc": true` under `"buildOptions"`:

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "xmlDoc": true
    }
}
```

If you have documentation in your code like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Documentation for FooClass
/// </summary>
public static class FooClass
{
    // ...
}
```

Then you should have an `xml` file in your output that looks like this:

```
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Foo.Bar</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:Foo.Bar.FooClass">
            <summary>
            Documentation for FooClass
            </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I use .NET Core 1.0-RC4 and VS.NET 2017 RC4 (new csproject format, no project.json). Also I already have the xml generated in my output folder but it's not published to the publish folder.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on **1.1.2**

`ResolvedFileToPublish` is the Item that publish uses to know which files to put in the publish folder. The `Include` is the file's source, and the `RelativePath` is where inside the publish folder the file should be placed.
`ComputeFilesToPublis`h is exactly as its name implies - it is the Target that gathers all the files to be published.

```
<Target Name="CopyDocumentationFile"
AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(FinalDocFile)"
                     RelativePath="@(FinalDocFile->'%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Just add this target to your `.csproj` and make sure that 
`GenerateDocumentationFile` is set to `true`

`<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>`

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795#issuecomment-289782712

Answer (score 1):

In Asp.net Core, if you are having trouble setting DocumentationFile to work, we can do that by setting  GenerateDocumentationFile property in .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```